# "lie on the basis of" versus "lie at the basis of"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions, writing

I often read in scientific papers a sentence of the form "X lies on the basis of Y." or "X lies at the basis of Y." to indicate that Y is caused by X in some fundamental way. Are both forms valid and common? (Maybe both are poor English?)

Comment: Take care that know whether "basis" is used as a term of art within some specific scientific field. If it is, then a simple linguistic analysis of its use isn't adequate. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_(linear_algebra) for example. Since you didn't give much context (what field of science? what is X and what is Y?) it's hard to say what is correct. The Google N-Gram viewer doesn't differentiate contexts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phrase "X lies at the basis of Y", while arguably clumsy, is used reasonably often in English. On the other hand, I do not believe that "X lies on the basis of Y" is something a native English speaker would say. Consider the following [Google Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lies+at+the+basis+of%2C+lies+on+the+basis+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) :

[image: Ngram for at/on the basis of]

Comment: Thanks for showing the Ngram tool. That is really convincing.

Answer (score 6):

Both are clumsy. Simply "X is the basis of Y" would be better, so for example "The rule of law is the basis of our freedom".